# How to add text under the logo of print order PDF on success page

Tags: magento2

I need to add text under the logo of print order PDF on success page in magento 2

Answer (score 0):

On the Frontpage, the print order action will not generate the PDF as Admin does. It will generate the HTML.

We should take a look at the print layouts under

> vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/layout

so override below files in your custom module or theme and add your custom text

```
vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/layout/sales_order_print.xml
vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/layout/sales_guest_print.xml
```